# Reduce function is not giving correct sum of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, sum, reduce

I have to sum 'n' number of matrices in R. These matrices are generated from columns of a multivariate matrix. I used Reduce function as per suggestions here in past questions and I am getting answer as a matrix too. But wrong sum. Can anyone identify the mistake in  my code. I tried the Reduce function for a small 5*5 matrix and the code of my attempt is given below.

```
library(MASS)
x<-mvrnorm(5,mu=c(0,0,0,0,0),diag(5))
p=5
n=nrow(x)
for(i in 1:n){
matrices[i]<-list(((diag(p)-   ((t(matrix(x[i,],1,5))%*%matrix(x[i,],1,5))/norm(x[i,],type="2")^2)))/norm(x[i,],type = "2"))
sum_matrices<- Reduce("+",matrices)
}
sum_matrices
```

Comment: `sum_matrices<- Reduce("+",matrices)` is correct code to sum matrices that are stored in a list. (You should move that line out of the `for` loop.) If you get the wrong result, the reason is probably in the rest of the code. However, you don't show the expected result, which means we can't help. (Also, always set a seed to make RNG results reproducible.)

Comment: @Roland hi sir, I want the sum of the matrices. The matrices are obtained from the row operation in x matrix initially called. When i tried the code inside for loop, i am getting matrices correctly and while doing their sum hands on, am getting different answer from reduce function.

Comment: Maybe you are doing it wrong when calculating the sum by hand? I just did so and `sum_matrices` is the sum of the matrices in the `matrices` list. Your code is working correctly.

Comment: `identical(matrices[[1]] + matrices[[2]] + matrices[[3]] + matrices[[4]] + matrices[[5]], sum_matrices)` returns `TRUE` as expected.

Comment: @Roland sir.. as per your comment when sum_matrices<- Reduce("+",matrices) placed out of the loop. the code works correctly. Thank you sir